# Magento 2 can't view blocks or pages in backend

Tags: magento2, blocks, backend, cms-pages

I just did a copy of my live website to set up a dev website but now on my dev website when I try to view the pages or blocks I get a log of errors.

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store does not exist

Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Store\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Store does not exist

```
#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:49]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:164]
#5 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->createChildComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:145]
#6 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->createChildComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php:238]
#7 Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:140]
#8 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->generateComponent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Generator/UiComponent.php:103]
#9 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Generator\UiComponent->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/GeneratorPool.php:81]
#10 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\GeneratorPool->process() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:343]
#11 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->generateElements() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:89]
#12 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->generateElements() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:129]
#13 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Page/Builder.php:55]
#14 Magento\Framework\View\Page\Builder->generateLayoutBlocks() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php:65]
#15 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:253]
#16 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php:875]
#17 Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php:414]
#18 Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/View/Result/Page.php:26]
#19 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page->setActiveMenu() called at [generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/View/Result/Page/Interceptor.php:24]
#20 Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->setActiveMenu() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Block.php:42]
#21 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Block->initPage() called at [vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Block/Index.php:43]
#22 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Block\Index->execute() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Block/Index/Interceptor.php:24]
#23 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Block\Index\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/AbstractAction.php:231]
#25 Magento\Backend\App\AbstractAction->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#26 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Block\Index\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#27 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Block\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php:143]
#28 Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#29 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Block\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#30 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Block\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Block/Index/Interceptor.php:39]
#31 Magento\Cms\Controller\Adminhtml\Block\Index\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:159]
#32 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:99]
#33 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#34 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#35 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#36 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#37 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:137]
#38 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php:24]
#39 Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#40 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
```

not sure how to go about fixing this new to running a magento site.

Answer (score 0):

First, match your live server configuration with the dev server configuration. Then run below commands on your dev server Magento root:

```
rm -rf vendor/*
composer install
rm -rf generated/*
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:d:c
<!-- For Production mode -->
php bin/magento s:s:d
<!-- For developer mode -->
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:f
php bin/magento c:c
```

Comment: Thanks once I run
php bin/magento s:s:d

I then run into this error during the process

MiBPHP Fatal error:  Class 'Magento\Eav\Model\Adminhtml\System\Config\Source\Inputtype' not found in /chroot/home/a921b67a/dev.zanibonilighting.com/html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Attribute/Source/Inputtype.php on line 12""

now looking into this

Comment: @Carter Please first delete all content from the vendor directory with the command: "rm -rf vendor/* " and then run the "composer install" command on Magento root. After this run all commands again.

Comment: @Carter I have updated the answer also with these changes.